# Unable to cast object to class in JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am creating a map to which I am adding a custom class object,

```
var member_map = {};
var memberAction = new MemberActions(members.data[i].id, members.data[i].name);
member_map[memberAction.id] = memberAction;
```

Now when I try to get back a MemberActions object from the map using an ID, i get an Object rather than a MemberActions object.

```
var memberAction = member_map[fetch_id];
```

How do I cast the object?

EDIT:
My class defn:

```
class MemberActions {
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this using the new ES6 class syntax?

Comment: Does any other code interact with member_map? Is it saved to JSON or something?

Comment: Is the `member_map` ever stored as text, perhaps as JSON? With just what you've provided here, what you describe shouldn't occur – http://jsfiddle.net/8tyec8dm/. But, JSON has no concept of custom types.

Comment: i am just instantiating a class instance and storing in the map

Comment: @AadiDroid: Can you post a complete example please (e.g. including `members` and `fetch_id`)? We cannot reproduce your issue. Also, how do you execute ES6, is there transpilation involved? Also, how did you determine that the object you got back was no `MemberAction` any more?

Answer (score 1):

JS doesn't have such a thing as object casting.

When you say you've got an Object this may mean when you try to `console.log(memberAction)` you get told that it's an Object - however it doesn't mean that isn't a MemberActions object.

To check the name of it, try:

```
console.log(memberAction.constructor.name)
```

`memberAction.constructor` should also contain the constructor you've defined.

Comment: `memberAction` is an instance and has no `.prototype`.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry I meant `constructor`! Edited.

Comment: Meh, using `.constructor.name` is still not exactly a best practise. You'd rather use `instanceof`. Also, `console.log` is usually quite good at figuring out what kind of custom "class" an object has.